# iTunes error : not enough memory available

Tags: ios, titanium, itunes

I just created my app using Titanium.
When done, the app can be installed on iTunes 11.1. When I upgrade to iTunes 11.2, there is no way to update the app. iTunes tells the app is not a valid iPod app...
If I try to add the app directly to iTunes 11.2, it tells me that there is nos enough memory available...

Does anyone encountered this problem before and know how to solve it... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pierrick, It is an issue which is reported [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16987). iTunes 11.2 contains a behavior change that prevents Titanium applications from installing to device via iTunes using the Titanium CLI, Titanium Studio, and Appcelerator Studio.

This only affects development and test device builds when using iTunes. Simulator testing and publishing to the App Store is unaffected.

There are several workarounds,

1. Do not upgrade iTunes, or [downgrade back to 11.1](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/174247/itunes-112-114-problem).
2. Choose your device during the packaging wizard [instead of using “iTunes Sync”](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Deploying_to_iOS_devices).

Reference : [Device deployment broken by recent iTunes update 11.2](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/05/device-deployment-broken-by-recent-itunes-update-11-2/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuavOe%2b/hmjTEU5z17OsoWKK/g4kz2EFye%2bLIHETpodcMRcRqMK%2bTFAwTG5toziV8R7bGKs1u0t8QUxbj)

Comment: I was hoping it could be something else... I saw that it worked installing the app directly on the phone but I wanted to share the app to someone... I'll tell him to downgrade his iTunes
Anyway, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to load the app into the device using xcode.

The context of this solution is for developers who currently use commandline titanium to build that app and part of the process automatically starts iTunes to load the app onto the device.

Here are the steps:

1. Quit iTunes as you will not be using iTunes.
2. Plug your device into your Mac.
3. Start XCode.
4. Choose Window->Organizer
5. Expect the Organizer window to open.
6. Choose "Device" on the top panel.
7. Expect the Devices to be loaded into the main panel.
8. Choose your device on the level panel.  It might* have a green dot next to it.
9. Click on the little tiny "arrow" icon in the icon list.
10. Click on "Add +" icon on lower panel.
11. Browse to your .ipa file.  You probably have never had to know where it is located in the titanium project before.  Mine was in `./build/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.ipa`
    from the commandline I did this to find it: `find . -type f |grep ipa$`
12. Unlock your device and expect to see the icon on your device.

    - If it does not have a green dot next to it perhaps you need to add it as a device used for development.  For that case there will be a "Use for Development" button in the organizer window.
    - If the dot is yellow, then you probably need to update the SDK in your version of XCode.  There is a link in the organizer window to take you to the proper website to do that.